# Webpacker binstubs not installing correctly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, webpacker

I have a perplexing issue here when trying to implement the Rails Webpacker gem into an existing application.

Unfortunately, I do not have much to offer in the way of debugging information, this is also an internal project, so I have limited options in terms of sharing the entire project source.

I am following the exact steps outlined here: https://github.com/rails/webpacker and have done it multiple times now, but during the `bundle exec rails webpacker:install` command (after running `bundle`), I see the message:

> Skipped webpack and webpack-dev-server since they already exist.
>   If you want to overwrite skipped stubs, use --force.

This binstubs most-definitely do not exist in my `bin/` directory. Either before or after the webpacker install.

I feel like I have tried everything at this point, and nothing seems to be working:

- Reinstalling the gem (multiple versions, even via Git)
- Manually creating the binstub from a different project (this "worked" until I tried to run the `webpacker:install:react` script).
- Manually running Yarn, attempting to `--force` create the binstubs
- Tried multiple different configuration tweaks in `webpacker.yml`

I am just out of ideas at this point. Anything else I should be checking, could try?

Comment: I don't have an answer for why they won't install, but they are fairly small scripts (< 50 lines each) that I imagine you could scaffold out a new project and then copy them manually from there into your existing project.

Answer (score 0):

This is a fix that worked for me:

I copied [these two files](https://github.com/rails/webpacker/tree/master/exe) into the `bin` directory of my app and then `bundle exec rails webpacker:check_binstubs` stopped complaining.

As a side effect it made my app deployable on my Paas with the standard buildpack.

Comment: See. I already tried this. And it did stop the complaining when I tried running `bundle exec rails`. But didn't work when I tried to run: `webpacker:install:react`